# How can I verify that a mongo index is working properly?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I've got a small collection of mp3s in a mongo 2.6 DB. A document from this "songs" collection might look like this:

`{_id: ..., name: "shagCarpet.mp3", tags: ["acapella", "rap"]}`

I expect this collection to grow rapidly in the near future, so I want to index this collection for easy searching. I created a multi-key index on the "tags" field like so:

`db.songs.createIndex({"tags": 1})`

Since the collection is currently small, I don't see a performance gain by adding the index. How can I verify that the index is working properly? Can I look at the data in the index? I'm aware of `db.songs.getIndexes()`, but that only regurgitates what I told Mongo when I created the index. I'd like to actually see what the index data looks like.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but the important thing is to run [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on your queries and confirm that the index is being used when you expect it to. BTW, that's a _multi-key_ index, not a compound index.

Comment: If you expect the collection to grow rapidly you need remeber that the index will slow down the writes and speed up the reads. It might be a good idea to wait with creating the index untill you have more information there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will get more info by using [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/):

```js
db.songs.find({"tags":"accapella"}).explain();
```

But I presume you wanna compare the speed of the query that is using the index with the speed of a normal collection scan(no index). You can force query to do a collection scan by using [hint()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) method ie. on _id.

```js
db.songs.find({"tags":"accapella"}).hint({_id:1}).explain();
```

Then compare explain() "millis" property between the two - you should see that the query without hint({_id:1}) is faster.

Answer (score 2):

The first step to determining if your indexes are working correctly is determining *how* you are going to be searching your database. Once you find the queries that will be run most frequently and/or will be most expensive, run them in the shell and append the `.explain()` call. For example:

```
db.songs.find(...).explain();
```

This will dump a lot of info out, part of which will tell you if an index was used, and if so which ones and in what order. For details of what it all means, see [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain-results/).

Answer (score 0):

use

`db.songs.find({"tags":"accapella"}).explain("executionStats");`

if `nReturned` equals `docsExamined`, it means that no unnecessary documents where examined and your index covers your query completely.

also here is a good article
https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/09/06/mongodb-investigate-queries-with-explain-index-usage-part-2/